# Tablayout custom view not taking full height android?

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout with 2 tabs. I am using custom view to set the tabs

Tablayout XML

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom View XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:andorid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
andorid:text="XXX" />
```

Java code for tab set up

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text, null);
    tabOne.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.tabText1));
    tabOne.setText(tabTitle[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text, null);
    tabTwo.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.tabText2));
    tabTwo.setText(tabTitle[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
}
```

This is my output
[image: Tabs not taking full height]

How do I match the height of the textview to tablayout height?

Comment: put custom xml textview hight 60dp

Comment: set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in tablayout

Comment: please refer this if you want to use only textview https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to do it programmatically

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Setting the params to textview

```
tabOne.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this try this layout for full access layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:andorid="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView 

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        andorid:text="XXX" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did u understood my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.. this is how i customize my tabs

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout)findviewById(R.id.tabs);

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabs.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                // Get TextView Element
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                  // change font
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
                  // change color
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                  // change size
                  ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(18);
                  // change padding
                  tabViewChild.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                  //..... etc...
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set height of tablayout wrap_content and set textview height 60dp/